# How to Install Oracle 10gR2 EE database on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: oracle

I've been able to install an Oracle 11gR2 EE database on Ubuntu 12.04 by using a tutorial found online.  But, I also need to run an Oracle 10g database (not XE).  Anyone know of or have a tutorial for 'How to Install Oracle 10gR2 Enterprise Edition Database on Ubuntu 12.04' on a 32 bit machine?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have VirtualBox installed on your Ubuntu, and then you can have 10gR2 on some OLD Linux dist inside VM, maybe CentOS?